# How to extract .zix file in Ubuntu?

Tags: extract

I am using Ubuntu 15.10,I have downloaded a Torrent file with .zix extension,is there any way to open and play it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would advise against trying to open that file.

> WinZix (Changed File) by WinZix, Inc.
>
> WARNING: WinZix is advertised as a compression tool however it appears from analysis of the files produced that it simply adds information to a file so that WinZix needs to be installed to access it. The program contains an adware component that must be installed with the program and the EULA for that component says you cannot use anti-adware software against it. In addition, use of such software may damage the component and make it difficult to remove. FILExt has removed links to this software and advises that you install it AT YOUR OWN RISK. If you receive a "compressed" ZIX file you are advised to warn the sender and ask them to resend the file in a more conventional format (e.g., ZIP)."

http://filext.com/file-extension/ZIX

edit: There do appear to be ways to open .zix files without installing spyware, such as http://www.kennethsorling.se/software/unzixwin.htm , but you would have to try running them in WINE, as they are for Windows. (This may or may not work successfully)